# FireMonkey Android How do I add a custom icon to the status bar

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Using the TNotificationCenter, the imgages from the standard $(BDS)\Delphi\bin\Artworl\Android\ map are placed in the Android status bar.
How can I add a custom made icon? or can I select an other image container. using: Delphi 10 Seattle with Mobile Addon pack.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't you do it [just like the other icons](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Application_Options)?